# create page for custom URL in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, url

I went through similar questions on SO but didn't get my answer. So I thought to put this together in a more simpler way here.

I have a website with url like :
`http://domain.com/user/user-name`   [ here user-name is dynamic and changes for every user, pretty obvious. ]  - This right now works perfectly fine.

Next :
I need to show pages as below for users in a url like :

```
http://domain.com/user/user-name/about

http://domain.com/user/user-name/contact

http://domain.com/user/user-name/posts
```

etc

**FYI** : I'm using ultimate member plugin to manage user profiles.

So I need to know how can I crate separate page for each of the above mentioned URL's custom to each of the section like about / contact / posts.

though I'm working with wordpress since quiet a time now but this problem makes me feel newbie to it. Please tell me step wise on how can I achieve this.

I've spent 2 days already working out various things.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the plugin called "Pods". It implemented the "URL Regex" as you required.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/pods/

Comment: thanks for answer, but I forgot to mention that users part in URL is already being managed via ultimate member plugin.